# Motion API not supported on HTC Radar?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, augmented-reality

i've been developing an application that uses augmented reality. it's the most basic example. i followed this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202984%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to the letter, and when i run the application on my HTC Radar, i get a popup that says "Motion API is not supported on this device." I checked prerequisites for a phone to be able to run AR apps, and i think that mine supports everything (WP7.5 Mango,...) but i might be wrong. Does anyone know if there's any workaround for this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my professional opinion, HTC Radar supports the motion API. In fact, I have developed an app which uses this api and it works just fine on HTC Radar. Where did you buy your phone?

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the tutorial, it might have something to do with how you are checking if the API is supported.

```
 // Check to see whether the Motion API is supported on the device.
  if (! Motion.IsSupported)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("the Motion API is not supported on this device.");
    return;
  }
```